# Why doesn't pgfplot take the normal font for ticks?

Tags: pgfplots, fonts

I have `libertine` as my base font. While using `pgfplots` to plot a graph, the axis labels do appear in the base font, but the tick label numbers revert to default computer modern. I have tried using `tick label style={font=\normalfont}` but no avail. How can I get the base font of the document on the tick label numbers?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}
[xlabel={Time 123(s)} ,ylabel={Distance (in)}, tick label style={font=\normalfont}]
\addplot [red,mark=*,line width=1.pt] coordinates {
(1,0.25)
(2,1)
(3,2.25)
(4,4)
(5,6.25)
(6,9)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the proposed duplicate: `tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}`.

Comment: Also consider to use centimeters instead of inches :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why doesn't it choose the base font of the document, and defaults to cm?

Comment: PGFPlots uses the math font by default for the tick numbers. The `libertine` package changes only the text font, but the math font remains as Computer Modern (try `123 $123$` somewhere in your document to confirm). The code that solves the issue (`assume math mode=true`) switches off math mode for the tick numbers, causing the text font to be used. Many font packages change only the text font, because the math font contains a lot of special characters that normal fonts don't provide so it would require many new characters to be designed in the style of the replacement font.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. It is also resolved by using `\usepackage{libertinust1math}` so that default math font is set in libertine